# Middas chassidus with judging beinoni favourably contradiction

Tags: halacha, chofetz-chaim

The Chofetz Chaim, in `חלק א כלל ג סעיף ז` writes about a beinoni

> וַאֲפִלּוּ אִם הַדָּבָר נוֹטֶה יוֹתֵר לְכַף חוֹבָה, (י) נָכוֹן מְּאֹד **שֶׁיִּהְיֶה הַדָּבָר אֶצְּלוֹ כְּמוֹ סָפֵק** וְאַל יַכְרִיעֵהוּ לְכַף חוֹבָה.
>
> Even if the matter appears really guilty, it is very proper to **leave it as a doubt in your mind** rather than judging him guilty.

In Beer Mayim Chaim (י), he writes:

> נכון מאד. ז''ל רבינו יונה, **יהיה הדבר אצלך כמו ספק ואל תכריעהו לכף חוב**. ונראה לי שכוונתו למדה טובה בעלמא ולא מצד הדין
>
> This is what Rabbeinu Yona writes: **leave the matter as a doubt** and don't judge guilty. And it appears to me he means as a pious practice but not the actual law.

He then shows a bunch of cases in the gemarra to be understood that meikkar hadin there's no chiyuv to judge favorably. Then a few paragraphs later writes

> וכל זה שכתבנו הוא מצד הדין אבל מצד מדה טובה אפילו הכף חוב הוא הרבה יותר מכף זכות צריך **לדון לכף זכות**, וראיה משבת (קכ''ז ע''ב) בכל המעשיות שהביא שם הגמרא היה הכף חוב הרבה והרבה יותר מהכף זכות ואפילו הכי צריך לדונו לכף זכות כמו שאמר שם העבודה כך היה וכשם וכו.
>
> Everything we've written [so far] is regarding the actual law. However, regarding the pious practice, even if the guilty side is much more compelling than the innocent side, you must **judge favourably**. A proof of this is in the Gemarrah in Shabbas with all of the cases the Gemarrah brings there where the guilty side was more compelling than the innocent side and even so one needs to judge favourably as it says over there "The job was such and just as...".

Which is it? Leave as suffik or judge favourably?

Comment: No I bolded correctly. The first two quotes say the midah tovah is to **leave as a suffik**. The third quote says the midah tovah is to **judge favourably**, not at all the same. I'll change the translation of midah tovah, and remove emphasis on "must" (as that's not the point)

Comment: I am not sure that that this is such a contradiction. On the one hand it is pious to remain uncertain whether he did wrong. On the other hand, it is pious to regard him favorably. Is this a contradiction?

Comment: Well which is the right thing for a pious person to do? It's either one or the other, and why was the chofetz chaim inconsistent? If I see a beinoni eat bacon, and I want to do the midah tovah, am I required to leave the matter undecided as who knows the background details of what I saw. Or must I make an absolute decision that it was pikuach nefesh and remove all doubts from my mind.

Comment: `and I want to do the midah tovah, am I required` that sentence is internally contradictory. If something is only a "middah tovah" then it is not a requirement.

Comment: I think we're arguing semantics.  The Torah and halacha define the practices of the masses as well as the "pious". The masses have to follow the ikkar hadin, and for those who want to go beyond the letter of the law, those that are called pious, there are practices which are are considered proper and those that are improper. Today it is improper to be "pious" and refrain from saying kriyas shema on one's wedding night, even though that used to be the law. The chofetz chaim is defining what the proper practice is for someone pious, and to that I see a contradiction. I cant assume its all proper

Comment: `The Torah and halacha define the practices of the masses as well as the "pious"` Once again you seem to assume that like halakha, piety has set parameters. AFAIK this is not the case. In many areas, the more the better. That would seem to be the case here. Something cannot (generally) be more halakhic or less halakhic, but it can be more pious or less pious. Rabbenu Avraham ben HaRambam makes pretty much this exact point in the beginning of the ethical part of HaMaspik.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44604/discussion-between-robev-and-mevaqesh).